# Is this a valid URL, and if so why does NSURL not recognize its query?

Tags: cocoa-touch, url, uri, nsurl

```
myscheme:?id=test
```

If I pass this to `[NSURL URLWithString:]` and print its `query` property, I get `nil`, but if I put a slash right after the colon (or two or three) it works fine.

Is this actually an invalid URL or is it a bug in `NSURL`?

According to some research, it appears to be a valid URL. From http://url.spec.whatwg.org/:

> An absolute URL must be a scheme, followed by ":", followed by scheme
>   data, optionally followed by "?" and a query.

*and (emphasis added)*

> The syntax of scheme data depends on the scheme and is typically
>   defined alongside it. For a relative scheme, scheme data must be a
>   scheme-relative URL. **For other schemes**, specifications or standards
>   must define scheme data within the constraints of **zero or more** URL
>   units.

Comment: That URL works fine for me. I use myscheme:?id=test and NSURL returned non-nil. And when I subsequently wrote an app that registered that scheme, it successfully was invoked using that URL, too. Personally, I would always use a scheme data, but it doesn't appear that you have to.

Comment: I guess the problem is the url doesn't recognize the *query* portion of the url (changed title to reflect this). Perhaps it is simply treating the query as scheme data, but that still seems wrong according to the definition.

Comment: Turns out it is being stored in the `resourceSpecifier` property of `NSURL`. And in fact, I can even omit the `?` and it will still interpret it as such, so that's acceptable. As long as I can get to the data I don't really care how `NSURL` interprets it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I was responding to the title. For what it's worth, it might be safer to use a URL with the `/` in case Apple ever changes this behavior to parse the `?id=test` as the query. Glad you solved the problem, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myscheme:?id=test` is a valid URL, and `NSURL` recognises it as such, by returning non-`nil` from `+URLWithString:`.

However, by RFC 1808, it doesn't conform in a manner such that `NSURL` recognises the `?` character as indicating a query string, so `-query` returns `nil`.

The good news here is that `NSURLComponents` has a slightly different parser which *will* recognise the `?` as indicating a query for your example:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"myscheme:?id=test"];
return components.query; // returns @"id=test"
```

If you still need to target iOS 6 or earlier with this code, I suggest using my [`KSURLComponents`](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/ksurlcomponents.html) class instead, which takes the same parsing approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering the part in the title (*Is this a valid URL?*), without taking NSURL into account (which I don’t know; it might be possible that NSURL doesn’t need valid URLs at all).

`myscheme:?id=test` is not a *valid URL*, because `myscheme` is not a registered URI scheme. You can find all valid URI schemes at http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html.

- http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.1:

  > Individual schemes are not specified by this document.  The process for registration of new URI schemes is defined separately by [[BCP35]](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp35).
- http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#writing:

  > A scheme must be registered.

Each URI scheme specifies the valid scheme data on its own, but the syntax [has to match](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.1) the grammar for absolute URIs:

> URI scheme specifications must define their own
>      syntax so that all strings matching their scheme-specific syntax will
>      also match the  grammar, as described in [Section 4.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-4.3).

The syntax is defined as:

```
absolute-URI  = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ]
```

But `hier-part` may be empty (if I didn’t overlook anything in STD 66). So if you are using a valid URI scheme, your URI seems to be valid (as long as that URI scheme doesn’t define special rules for the scheme data, which it probably does).

Comment: I think it's incorrect to say a scheme must be registered for a URL to be valid. None of the RFCs say this, and the document you are quoting that does is a "living standard document" that, as of late December 2013, has a bright red box with ellipses next to the phrase, presumably indicating that statement is still being considered and revised.

Comment: @algal: [STD 66, section 3.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.1) says: "Each URI begins with a scheme name that refers to a specification for assigning identifiers within that scheme." Some lines below: "The scheme registry maintains the mapping between scheme names and their specifications." It refers to [BCP 35](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp35), wich says in [section 1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp35#section-1): "there is a single namespace for registered values" (in contrast to what the obsoleted RFC 2717 defined).

Comment: Interesting. So if we suppose the implication is that the scheme registry maintains the mapping of _all_ scheme names, then it's not a scheme name if it's not registered, and then it's not a URL. Ok. But that sure leaves a hell of a lot of URLs floating around that are invalid but well-formed! :)

Comment: @algal: (Note that all this is only me digging in the RFC‘s, I don’t have firm knowledge here; I’d love to be corrected.) Yes, I think so. [Anyone](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp35#section-3) could register schemes that are already in use: "Previously unregistered URI schemes discovered in use may be registered by third parties on behalf of those who created the URI scheme". -- However, without such a (registered) specification we can only know to some extent if it would be "well-formed", as scheme specs could define additional rules for the URI syntax.

Comment: Agreed. It seems like there's a tension between the world of the specs, which envision public URIs exchanged over the network, and the real world. The latter also includes a proliferation of private URLs, confined to one host or even to one process, where they serve as a DSL for naming records and decomposing resource loading. OS X provides URLs for individual address book records, mail records, calendar records, etc.. For me, all motivated by my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807430/custom-url-scheme-as-adapter-on-existing-url-schemes

Comment: The WHATWG URL spec seems to have changed. Instead of "must", it now says "should": https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-syntax