# Is there a name for a URL with no protocol?

Tags: url, uri, naming-conventions, naming

A simple URL would normally have the pattern of `protocol://host:port`:

> http://localhost:8080

But if I omit the protocol:

> localhost:8080

Is it still a URL or does it have a different name?

I am aware of the existence of protocol-relative URLs, is this also a case of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localhost:8080` can’t be a [relative reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2), as these have to begin with `//` (in which case it would be a *network-path reference*, typically called *protocol-relative reference*), with `/`, or with a path segment that doesn’t contain `:`.

(For the latter case, you could use `./localhost:8080`.)

#### `localhost:8080` as part of `http://localhost:8080`

In the URI `http://localhost:8080`, the part `localhost:8080` is the [**authority** component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2).

The part `localhost` is the [**host** subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2), the part `:8080` is the [**port** subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3).

#### `localhost:8080` as URI

`localhost:8080` itself is, syntactically, also an URI:

- `localhost` would be the [scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1)
- `8080` would be the [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3)

But as `localhost` is not a [registered URI scheme](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes), `localhost:8080` is currently [not a valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19400780/1591669) URI.